# Tool to find out why a process hangs

Tags: windows

Are there any GUI tools for Windows that can help identify the problem with a program that stopped responding to user actions? When a program freezes, I can usually see in the Windows task manager that the program consumes a large amount of CPU, but no reasons as to why this is happening.

Is the process performing some heavy I/O operations that slow it down? Is it trying to reach something over the network with no success? Does it lack security permissions to perform some OS operations?

Comment: What's the source code language of the program?

Comment: @rrirower, this is not essential since I'm not planning to access the tool programmatically or modify its source code